# Add (PHP) echo Css Style

Tags: css

This one is original and works properly.

```
echo "<font face=arial size=2><b>Users Online: $n_u_online</b>";
?>
```

https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-HSDMjVHkrOA/YFt3AdZd8tI/AAAAAAABFo0/VjKId5hHbmElgfcgIK7x90TiPJjU0sJGQCLcBGAsYHQ/s16000/Ads%25C4%25B1z2.png

But I want to do this with Css. I coded it like this but I cannot print the online issue "$ n_u_online" is reflected on the site

```
echo '<div class="view-meta">Users Online: $n_u_online</div>';
?>
```

https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-fiQtwYBO2Fo/YFt3AY2JbWI/AAAAAAABFo4/KhRJb7Q6XMQK4_ddLjGZAZWF64dm4XaogCLcBGAsYHQ/s16000/Ads%25C4%25B1z.png

Help me please.

Comment: double quotes allows variables to be printed inside, single quotes not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
echo "<div class='view-meta'>Users Online: $n_u_online</div>";
```

Or this :

```
echo '<div class="view-meta">Users Online: '.$n_u_online.'</div>';
```

Comment: Thank you this happened. Both Work.
but can we format the "50 queries in 0.227 seconds" font?
https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-NrcfaVNv-dk/YFt5fYa4qrI/AAAAAAABFpE/4COKpIaZ_bYQGgiDzDZTVFJY2yWZMahkACLcBGAsYHQ/s16000/Ads%25C4%25B1z3.png

Comment: Need more code , after this line what you have ?

Comment: the both code working perfect, but I thought the second part  remain  the same ( 50 queries in 0189 seconds ) but it was my mistake, thanks again,